# ionic- build .Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
```

how to resolve this . i tried many solution but nothing worked

Comment: _When do you get this?_ please provide an [mcve]

Comment: ionic run android --prod     . At the time of apk command

Comment: [edit] the question please. Also.. can you add the output for `cordova requirements` to the question?

Comment: this command not working.
 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: have you added android platform?

Comment: yes i added.
ionic platform add android

Comment: did you run `cordova requirements` in your project folder?

Comment: Error: Cordova does not know requirement; try `cordova help` for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: requirements _plural_

Comment: thanks
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0 ;
Android SDK: installed true ;
Android target: installed android-24,android-25;
Gradle: installed

Comment: try `ionic run android` without prod flag

Comment: same error like above

Comment: earlier i tried cordova 7 which created this problem . so i got back to cordova 6.5 but now finding the same problem

Comment: does i need to set gradle path also in environmental variable

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10970

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: This worked for me.
i deleted gradle folders from users>.gradle>wrapper>dists ...
 downloaded the required gradle as per project on project run command.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: great.. add that as an answer.

Comment: there was little issue after that too. but removing whole .gradle folder in C:/user .it resolved all. When i ran the ionic build command ,it automatically downloaded correct gradle acc. to my project specifications.
How to add this as an answer ?

Comment: there is an answer block below the question..